# cannot save all pdf elements of ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

**UPDATE for reproducibility**

Whenever I make a plot in ggplot, I am unable to save it as a PDF and reliably retain all elements of the PDF. For example, I have the following:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=mpg, group=cyl, fill=as.factor(cyl))) +
  geom_density(adjust=1.5, alpha=.6, col= "black") +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
        panel.border = element_blank(),
        text=element_text(family="times", size=20),
        axis.text=element_text(family="times", size=20),
        legend.text=element_text(family="times", size=20),
        strip.text=element_text(family="times", size=20),
        legend.position = "none")+
  scale_x_continuous(expand=c(0,0)) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0,0))
```

which saves fine as a .png:
[image]

but is missing elements when saved as a .pdf:
[image]

I get this same plot with missing elements when I save it from the plot panel of RStudio, use ggsave, use the pdf() print() dev.off() method, etc. I thought it might be preview (I am on a mac), but the plot looks the same in Adobe. Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

I am running r version 4.3.0 through RStudio version 2023.09.1+494 on macOS version 14.0.

Comment: I think you'll need to add some more debugging info.  Not sure what will be relevant, but you could start by listing your OS, pdf driver (e.g. cairo), R version etc...  Is it always elements at the edges that get omitted? i.e. could be an issue with page margins?

Comment: apologies and updated

Comment: @mrFlick that solved it! If you want to put that in an answer (maybe with a little explanation) I will give you the answer check mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default font families in R are "sans", "serif", and "mono". If you just want a serif font, use "serif" to get something that should look kind of like Times New Roman.

Note that graphics devices do support different fonts. You can get a list of all the families supported by the PDF `names(pdfFonts())`. On my system at least I do see "Times" listed. If I run your code with an upper case "T", I do see the labels I expect. So make sure to match those values exactly. And it turns out "serif" is just an alias for "Times" in this case.